# How to use negative lookahead to remove search between two chars

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
string1 = '%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1'
```

output

```
'-a', '_-', '_s1'
```

Need to remove all selection between '%' and 's'

Attempt 1:

```
re.findall("[-_a-z0-9]+(?![^%]*\s)", string1)
```

result:

```
['example_1', '0s-a', 'example-', 's_-', 'example', 's_s1']
```

Attempt 2:

```
re.findall("[-_a-z0-9]+(?![^(]*\))", string1)
```

result:

```
['40s-a', 's_-', 's_s1']
```

attempt 2 is sorta close expect it matched '40s' which is between % & s. and overmatched 's' in the other entries.

expected output

```
['-a', '_-', '_s1']
```

EDIT:

Want to confirm how to not search between % & s.

```
string2 = 'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1'
```

expected output:
    ['abc123', '-a', '_-', '_s1'

```
string3 = 'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(examples3).40s'
```

expected output:
    ['abc123', '-a', '_-']

Comment: can you show us the expected output after all those?

Comment: The expected output ['-a', '_-', '_s1']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use the "negative" approach, with `re.split` using non-greedy match to match chars between `%` and `s`: the regex is then very simple

Only kludge: you need to filter empty fields (start of the string)

```
import re

result = [x for x in re.split("%.*?s",'%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1') if x]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['-a', '_-', '_s1']
```

edit: that simple expression doesn't work if parentheses contain "s" character, you can then replace the expression by a more complex one:

```
%\(.*?\).*?s|%.*?s
```

(which is an expression requiring parentheses OR the previous simple expression: allows to match even if no parentheses)

Comment: This almost works, except if string = ''%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s', it also captures the last characters ['example3)s']

Comment: I have tested with your input and I get `['-a', '_-']` which is expected.

Comment: Apologies for all the extraneous cases I am adding after. It seems when testing, I did not achieve the desired result is because the example string is similiar to this string4 = '%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(examples3).40s' . This causes a cut into the examples before the finals s

Comment: my answer seems to cover even the cases you added afterwards. consider accepting the answer that suits your needs best (besides of upvotes)

Comment: `(Pdb) string4 = '%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(examples3).40s'`
`(Pdb) [x for x in re.split("%.*?s", string4) if x]`

`['-a', '_-', '3).40s']`

only `['-a', '_-']` should match

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the regex

> %[^s]*s([^%]+)

The matches are stored in the group

```
import re

regex = r"%[^s]*s([^%]+)"

test_str = "%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1"

subst = "\\1,"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

or if you want them in an array

```
import re

regex = r"%[^s]*s([^%]+)"

test_str = "%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1"

subst = "\\1,"

result = re.findall(regex,test_str);

if result:
    print (result)
```

check [online compiler](http://ideone.com/tTDxVA)

Comment: could you explain what the regex is doing. I somewhat understand the first part, but lost on the second part s([^%]+).

Comment: [^%] matches anything which is not "%", so ([^%]+) matches everything util an "%" occurs , check out https://regex101.com/r/i6qOES/1, the green indicates the captured group

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
>>> string1 = '%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1'
>>> print filter(None, re.split(r'::', re.sub(r'%[^s]*s', '::', string1)))
['-a', '_-', '_s1']

>>> string2 = 'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1'
>>> print filter(None, re.split(r'::', re.sub(r'%[^s]*s', '::', string2)))
['abc123', '-a', '_-', '_s1']
```

Here:

- `%[^s]*s`: matches everything between `%` and `s` characters
- `sub` function replaces each of `%...s` with `::`
- `split` function splits on `::`

Comment: How would it match preceding characters. Such as 'string2 = 'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1''

would you use something like this '([^%]+)%[^s]*s' ?|

Detailed output added to description

Answer (score 1):

Based on these test strings:

```
tests=('%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1', 
       'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s_-%(example3)s_s1')
```

You can do:

```
for s in tests:
    print re.findall(r'(?:s|^)([^%\n]+)(?=%|$)', s)
```

Result:

```
['-a', '_-', '_s1']
['abc123', '-a', '_-', '_s1']
```

Comment: Is the regex searching between 's' and any character not '%'?

what if the the string1 = 'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s'

Comment: @user1539348:  Yes. What is your expected output with `'abc123%(example_1).40s-a%(example-2)s'`? Perhaps you should add several example input and desired outputs.

Comment: I have added the extra case. Expected results would be     ['abc123', '-a', '_-', '_s1'

Comment: I have added one more testcase that seems to be breaking.